# GWT - Passing arguments when deploying with google plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, deployment, compiler-construction

I'm using GWT + GAE in Eclipse and I use the Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE) to deploy my app to my server. Although I can modify my compiler arguments when launching my app in DevMode (in "Run configurations" menu), it seams I cannot find a way to pass additional arguments (like -deploy) to the GWT compiler when the app is deployed using GPE.

Any solution here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: it seams that the GWT compiler uses the arguments passed in the "Advanced" panel (when selecting "GWT compile project...", which is in the same menu as the deploy to app engine option). This is both for local as well as the deployment gwt compilation.